# How to fix flexbox alignment issues in Internet Explorer 11 using CSS?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm currently working on a web project that utilizes CSS flexbox for layout and design. Everything looks great in modern browsers, but I'm encountering issues specifically with Internet Explorer 11. The problem I'm facing is that the flexbox properties, such as flex-direction and justify-content, don't seem to work as expected in IE 11. The elements are not aligning correctly, and the layout is completely broken. I've tried adding vendor prefixes and researching compatibility issues, but I haven't been able to find a solution that works. Here's a simplified version of my CSS code:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Is there a known workaround or any specific considerations I need to take into account to make Flexbox work properly in Internet Explorer 11? I appreciate any advice or suggestions to resolve this issue.

Comment: You might be better off placing the flex rules in an @supports query and serving up IE11 something simpler — like mobile styles.